# EW theory vertices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, electroweak, chirality

I'm trying to undertand the following vertex:

Initial state of up and anti-down quarks with finalk state made of $W^+$ boson. Does it go with left or right projector? I think that from Lagrangian it should go with left projector but the vertex with $e^+$ and $W^-$ in initial state and $\bar{\nu}_e$ in the final one goes with right projector and this is not read from Lagrangian.

Accordingly to my professor, the case R-positron with $W^-$ to give R-antineutrino has a vertex that goes with $\gamma^\mu P_R$, so what I want to know is how extract this vertex if the Lagrangian does not contain that term, just $P_R\gamma^\mu P_L = \gamma^\mu P_L$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you just wrote the Lagrangian terms you are looking at. 
Destroying a Left-handed *u* and R antidown to create a *W*<sup>+</sup> corresponds to the vertices
$$
W_\mu^- \overline {d} P_R\gamma^\mu P_L u + W_\mu^+ \overline {u} P_R\gamma^\mu P_L d ,
$$
while destroying a R-positron and a *W*<sup>-</sup> to yield a R-antineutrino to 
$$
W_\mu^-\overline {e} P_R\gamma^\mu P_L \nu +  W_\mu^+ \overline{\nu}  P_R\gamma^\mu P_L e ~~~, 
$$
where you focus on the first term in each line.

Note half the species, the R leptons/quarks and L anti leptons/antiquarks are simply *missing* from these couplings.  (In an, impossible, notional world with no masses, these components would be missing *everywhere* and all spinors would be Weyl, and projectors would be superfluous.)

Further note L is in no way privileged over R: it is simply a convention of us mooring chirality on leptons/quarks instead of antileptons/antiquarks. (Sometimes this convention is subverted in QFT texts or GUT arraying.)

Comment: Destroying a positron requires of $\bar{e}$ while destroying $W^-$ needs of $W^-$ field. Plus creating $\bar{\nu}$ suppose the necessity of $\nu$ field, so the corresponding Lagrangian term that leads to this proicess is the one that goes as $\gamma^\mu P_L$, not $\gamma^\mu P_R$ as books say. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm not sure what your undisclosed books says where. I suspect the best thing to do is to go review the Dirac equation and single out the creation and destruction and helicity pieces of the spinors. The field that destroys a positron creates an electron, as well.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how the vertex in $\gamma^\mu P_R$ appears since Lagrangian has not right projector. I've always been told that to get vertices you need to rib out fields of interaction Lagrangian and the remaining is the vertex. Nevertheless, there is no $P_R$ in Lagrangian, but there it is in vertex. I'm stuck

Comment: You are telling me this: $\bar{\psi_L}\gamma^\mu = (P_L\psi)^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^\mu = \bar{\psi}P_R\gamma^\mu = \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu P_L$. So we don't get $P_R$ what does appear in vertex, this is why I don't understand the vertex with $P_R$, I don't see where this right projector comes

Comment: I've made an edit in order to be more clear about what I want to know

Comment: Then you are telling me that the vertex $\gamma^\mu P_R$ does not exist, so my professor is wrong? I think that understand all the mathematics with the projectors that you are explaining, so since there is no $P_R$ term, positron + $W^-$ to produce antinuetrino goes with $\gamma^\mu P_L$ instead of $\gamma^\mu P_R$, or not? They are 'missing' from this couplings as you say

Comment: I just stuck all the (superfluous) Left and Right projectors where they belong. The anti leptons and antiquarks in *all* expressions are *all* Right handed, and the L such simply do not enter in these expressions, as they are absent from the charged weak currents. It behooves you to confirm that by writing down all Dirac component spinors as he presumably drilled your in the Dirac equation phase.

Comment: From Dirac spinors and this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74529/weak-interaction-and-the-chirality-of-anti-particles?rq=1 I undertsnd that since the antineutrino is in the final state, so it goes with $v(p, s)$, and it is R, then the vertex should be $\gamma^\mu P_L v(p, s)$. $P_L v(p, s)$ is R as you can deduce from the linked  post. This is contrary to what my professor said, so now I don't know who's right. I'm really confused with all these, but thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, the question you found is a *duplicate*, and it is impeccable. I'm pretty sure your professor is referring to the R projector on the left of the $γ^ μ$s. Charge conjugation flips the spin, and hence chirality.

Comment: I'm going to make another post explaining what was the process of my professor to end up with a right projector in order to unveil if what she did has some sense or not